# Joi date (when optional) validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

My function accepts an object which contains `fromDate` and `toDate` (both are optional).
I want to write a [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) validation that validates the object

1. `fromDate` and `toDate` are date type and optional
2. If both exists `fromDate` <= `toDate`

Help please!

```js
function getReport(args) {
    const { fromDate, toDate } = args;
    // validation
    // bl
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below schema works for me.

```js
Joi.object()
  .keys({
    fromDate: Joi.date().iso().optional(),
    toDate: Joi.date().iso().optional()
  })
  .when(Joi.object({ fromDate: Joi.exist(), toDate: Joi.exist() }), {
    then: Joi.object({
      toDate: Joi.date().iso().min(Joi.ref('fromDate'))
    })
  })
```